# Is it possible to put the trained model on other servers for use. Because accessing www.clarifai.com from our server has a serious delay

Tags: clarifai

Is it possible to put the trained model on other servers for use.
Because accessing [www.clarifai.com](http://www.clarifai.com) from our server has a serious delay

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately, I wanted to do the same and asked the team, but you cannot use the model outside of their API.